# Template template parameters and function call

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to write a function that receives a template template parameter and call another function that also receives a template template parameter. I want to use the parameter received in the first to call the second but I don't find a way to do it. Example:

```
template <template <typename> class AClass, typename AnotherClass>
AClass<typename AnotherClass::InnerType> bar(AnotherClass& a)
{
    AClass<typename AnotherClass::InnerType> result;
    return result;
}

template <template <typename> class AClass, typename AnotherClass>
AClass<typename AnotherClass::InnerType> foo(AnotherClass& a)
{
    auto result = bar<AClass, AnotherClass>(a);
}
```

The error I receive is: error: missing template arguments before ',' token

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: That in the call bar<AClass, AnotherClass>(a); it expects a template parameter for AClass

Comment: `bar` should be placed before `foo`.

Comment: @Evg Why not write an answer that explains why that is so?

Comment: @Evg Yes, of course. They are in different files and I have put the corresponding include. It's just an example. I'll edit to change the order anyways.

Comment: @Swordfish, I'm not sure whether it is really an answer.

Comment: Now your code works (apart from `foo` not returning a value). I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: @Evg In my case it's not working, the compiler expects AClass to receive a parameter.

Comment: Then I suggest you post the code that **doesn't** work.

Comment: @Evg I have edited the question with the error the compiler gives to me.

Comment: @aafso Also compiler and version, please.

Comment: If you add `return result;` into `foo`, the code in your question does compile. The problem is somewhere else. My guess is that you call `foo` incorrectly.

Comment: @Evg I was just about to say please include `return result;` :)

Comment: "The error I receive is: error: missing template arguments before ',' token" In which line?? I don't get it. How hard is it to write a [mcve] and post the exact error message including the line number?? You don't return any value from `foo()`.

Answer (score 0):

If I add the obviously missing return statement i cannot reproduce your problem:

```
template<typename T>
struct qux {
    using InnerType = T;
};

template <template <typename> class AClass, typename AnotherClass>
AClass<typename AnotherClass::InnerType> bar(AnotherClass& a)
{
    AClass<typename AnotherClass::InnerType> result;
    return result;
}

template <template <typename> class AClass, typename AnotherClass>
AClass<typename AnotherClass::InnerType> foo(AnotherClass& a)
{
    auto result = bar<AClass, AnotherClass>(a);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    qux<int> b;
    foo<qux>(b);
}
```